# Simple JS require/include/import tool using concatenation in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, gruntjs

I'm looking for a simple JavaScript require / concat tool for JavaScript in node.

For example, say I have 4 JS files:

**each.js**

```
function each(arr, fn, scope) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        fn.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
    }
}
```

**on.js**

```
// addEventListener wrapper:
function on(target, type, callback) {
    target.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
}
```

**onEach.js**

```
// require: each.js


// require: on.js


// Add an event listener to multiple elements:
function onEach(targets, type, callback) {
    each(targets, function(target) {
        on(target, type, callback);
    });
}
```

**all.js**

```
// require: each.js


// require: on.js


// require: onEach.js
```

The last two files have dependencies. I would like to know if there is a command-line node tool that will build these using concatenation to replace each require comment/statement/function call with the proper dependency. The built versions of each.js and on.js would be left untouched, and the built versions of onEach.js and all.js would both look like this:

```
function each(arr, fn, scope) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        fn.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
    }
}


// addEventListener wrapper:
function on(target, type, callback) {
    target.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
}


// Add an event listener to multiple elements:
function onEach(targets, type, callback) {
    each(targets, function(target) {
        on(target, type, callback);
    });
}
```

I've looked at [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp), [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html), and some other tools, but I haven't yet found a setup that I like. Any suggestions would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I think you're lookin' for [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: @elclanrs browserify adds a lot of unneaded wrapper code to the built files. I'm looking for something quite a bit simpler.

Comment: A lot? This is all Browserify adds AFAIK: https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/cbb2d384d5ee9e3a1a30, plus a small require function for each module.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Browserify is actually a good solution for you.  I know you mentioned in the comments that it isn't, but have you seen these options?

```
--no-builtins

Turn off builtins. This is handy when you want to run a bundle in node which
provides the core builtins.

--no-commondir

Turn off setting a commondir. This is useful if you want to preserve the
original paths that a bundle was generated with. 

--bare 

Alias for both --no-builtins, --no-commondir, and sets --insert-global-vars
to just "__filename,__dirname". This is handy if you want to run bundles in
node.
```

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify